# Itelligencia url rewriter and slug like url's in asp.net webforms / IIS

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

We have inherited an old asp.net 4 webforms project that uses intelligencia url rewriter.

Currently, the product URLs look along the lines of and work fine : -

https://somedomain.com/Catalog/d4d468e8-1fe8-4648-8acf-0aac0d0d120f

Is there anyway to, instead, have something like : -

https://somedomain.com/Catalog/name-of-some-product

which would load the same as https://somedomain.com/Catalog/68e8d4d4-1fe8-4648-8acf-0aac0d0d120f

There are rewrite rules in the web.config file but nothing I can see relating to slug like urls - can it be done with Intelligencia on IIS ?

Thanks

Sm

Answer (score 0):

This is all about routing so you need to modify the route parameters file to get what you are looking for. You should be able to find a reference of it in your global.ascx.cs file.